# javascript, jQuery: how to save values instead of the references

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following lines to store the location of an object.

```
var lightboxTop = $('#lightbox').css('top');
var lightboxLeft = $('#lightbox').css('left');
```

I'm successively moving this object in my element, and I want to restore it previous position with the stored variables.

But, I'm afraid javascript is saving the values by reference so I lose the initial positions. Am I correct ? How can I solve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those values returned are not stored by reference. If you change the `top` and `left` style of the element, it will not affect your stored values.

Primitive types in javascript are not passed by reference.

```
    var a = "a";

    var b = a;

    a = "c";

    alert(b);  // alerts "a"
    alert(a); // alerts "c"
```

or

```
    var a = 1;

    var b = a;

    a = 3;

    alert(b);  // alerts "1"
    alert(a); // alerts "3"
```

Objects are passed by reference:

```
    var a = {one:"one"};

    var b = a;

    a.one = "three";

    alert(b.one);  // alerts "three"
    alert(a.one); // alerts "three"
```

Comment: Not 'passed', that would imply being used as an argment, and even then all arguments are passed by value (and the value of all variables is a reference pointing to to either a Primitive or a Host Object like object).

Comment: @Sean - Thanks for the note. I'll be the first to admit that my javascript nomenclature is often less than perfect.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it's not storing any reference, but the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has no support for 'by reference'.

```
var a = 1; // a is 1
var b = a; // b is set to the value of a, that is, 1
a = 2; // a is set to 2, b is still 1
```

The only way to pass 'references' is to share the object that the variable is a property of

```
var props = {};
props.a = 1;
var newprops = props; // props === newprops = true, both variables point to the same reference
newprops.a // is 1
props.a = 3;
newprops.a // is 3
```

And what happens if we replace one of the variables pointing to the reference to the object?

```
props = {}; // props === newprops = true, props is set to a NEW object, newprops still points to the old one
props.a = 2; // is 2
newprops.a; // is still 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try jQuery.clone() method, like so:

```
var l = $('#lightbox');
var start = l.clone().hide();
```

then move `l` around, remove it afterwards and redisplay `start`.